# Form is submitting even though JavaScript is picking up invalid data

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm trying to stop my form sending if the data entered is invalid, the JavaScript is running and seeing that each field is invalid but is still sending the data and redirecting the user, rather than keeping them on that page.

```
//test to see informtion is valid
$('form[name="input"]').submit(function(event){
    alert('user has submitted the form....');
    var vaild = true;
    $('form input').each(function(){
        var data = $(this).val();
        console.log(data);
        if(!$(this).hasClass('valid'))valid = false;
        console.log($(this).hasClass('valid'));
    });
    console.log('valid:'+valid);
    if(vaild) return true;
    return false;

    }); 

<form name="input" method="post" action="regprocess.php"> <!--here after the form is submitted it is directed to the check page-->
   <ol> 
          <div align="center">
            <table width="400" border="1">
              <tr>

                <td><li><label for="fname">First Name (Max Lenght 15)</label></li></td>
                <td><input class="text" type="text" name="fname" /></li></td>

              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><li><label for="lname">Last Name (Max Lenght 15)</label></li></td>
                <td><input class="text" type="text" name="lname"/></li></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><li><label for="dob">DOB</label></li></td>
                <td><input class="date" id="datepicker" type="text" name="dob"/></li></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><li><label for="email">Email:</label></li></td>
                <td><input class="email" type="email" name="email"/></li></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="23"><li><label for="username">Username: (Max Length 10)</label></li></td>
                <td><input class="un" type="text" name="username"/></li></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><li><label for="password">Password:</label></li></td>
                <td><input class="password" type="password" name="password"/></li></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><li><label for="password2">Confirm Password:</label></li></td>
                <td><input class="password" type="password" name="password2"/></li></td>
              </tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/></td>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

**You have a typo:** `vaild` should be `valid`.

You are defining the (misspelled) variable here:

```
var vaild = true;
```

But you are updating a different, previously undeclared (but correctly spelled!) one here:

```
if(!$(this).hasClass('valid'))valid = false;
```

So your `vaild` variable is always true, and it's the one you're using to return `true`/`false` (and thus always allowing the form to submit).

I've made the fix here (omitting the debugging code and adding a couple of suggestions):

```
$('form[name="input"]').submit(function(event) {
    var valid = true;
    $('form input').each(function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('valid')) {
            valid = false;
            return false; // break out of the for-loop
        }
    });
    return valid; // simply return the variable
});
```